# Adding new object to custom array adapter with help of AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to add new Client with help of dialog, but it looks like my edit text does not exist.

It looks like all ids are right and all is good with activity live cycle, but I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference at dartdev.intent.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:122)
```

On the line:

```
     String nameValue = clientName.getText().toString().trim();
```

Can anyone explain what went wrong?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    ArrayList<Client> clientListItems = new ArrayList<Client>();
    ClientAdapter clientAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        initClients();

        clientAdapter = new ClientAdapter(this, clientListItems);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(clientAdapter);

        Button buttonView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addListItem);

        buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                setAddingDialog();

            }
        });



    }

    /*
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Button buttonView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addListItem);

        buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //listItems.add(0, Utils.hashGenerator(25));
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //DialogFragment newFragment = new AddingDialog();
                //newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "adding");
                setAddingDialog();

            }
        });
    }
    */

    void initClients(){
        clientListItems.add(new Client("alex", 1265, new Wallet("151516456464564654", 4564.56), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
        clientListItems.add(new Client("mike", 26, new Wallet("465456445644123231", 1645.2), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
        clientListItems.add(new Client("tray", 145, new Wallet("12315465489789", 0.00), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
        clientListItems.add(new Client("vincent", 999, new Wallet("3213546549789", 1000000.01), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
        clientListItems.add(new Client("venom", 666, new Wallet("321154654654798", 145.6), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
    }

    void setAddingDialog(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();

        final EditText clientName = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientName);
        final EditText clientId = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientId);
        final EditText clientWallet = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientWallet);
        final EditText clientBalance = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientBalance);

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_new_client, null))
                .setPositiveButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String nameValue = clientName.getText().toString().trim();
                        int idValue = Integer.valueOf(clientId.getText().toString().trim());
                        String walletValue = clientWallet.getText().toString().trim();
                        double balanceValue = Double.valueOf(clientBalance.getText().toString().trim());
                        clientListItems.add(new Client(nameValue, idValue, new Wallet(walletValue, balanceValue), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();

    }
}
```

**dialog_add_new_client.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newClientName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="name"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newClientId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="id"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newClientWallet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="walletNumber"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newClientBalance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="balance"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this code:

```
 Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();

 final EditText clientName = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientName);
 final EditText clientId = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientId);
 final EditText clientWallet = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientWallet);
 final EditText clientBalance = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientBalance);
```

after

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_new_client, null))
            .setPositiveButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String nameValue = clientName.getText().toString().trim();
                    int idValue = Integer.valueOf(clientId.getText().toString().trim());
                    String walletValue = clientWallet.getText().toString().trim();
                    double balanceValue = Double.valueOf(clientBalance.getText().toString().trim());
                    clientListItems.add(new Client(nameValue, idValue, new Wallet(walletValue, balanceValue), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

When you assign your EditTexts, the dialog custom view is not yet inflated, so they are all null. And also you need to call `findViewById` on the inflated view and not on the alert dialog.

Don't call `show()` while you set your custom layout but only in the end, after your textviews initialization, by calling:

```
alertDialog.show();
```

**EDIT**

Declare your EditTexts as global fields of your activity, so they don't need to be final.

Summing up, change your `setAddingDialog()` this way:

```
private EditText clientName;
private EditText clientId;
private EditText clientWallet;
private EditText clientBalance;

void setAddingDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_new_client, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView)
           .setPositiveButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String nameValue = clientName.getText().toString().trim();
                    int idValue = Integer.valueOf(clientId.getText().toString().trim());
                    String walletValue = clientWallet.getText().toString().trim();
                    double balanceValue = Double.valueOf(clientBalance.getText().toString().trim());
                    clientListItems.add(new Client(nameValue, idValue, new Wallet(walletValue, balanceValue), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
                }
            })
           .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    clientName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.newClientName);
    clientId = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.newClientId);
    clientWallet = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.newClientWallet);
    clientBalance = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.newClientBalance);

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

**UPDATE**
You need to call `findViewById` on the inflated view and not on the alert dialog. Check the code I updated.

Comment: Thanks, but it not help.Previous error in previous place.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. You need to call `findViewById` on the inflated view and not on the alert dialog. Check the code I updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your dialog layout before this-:

```
builder.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_new_client);

 final EditText clientName = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientName);
        final EditText clientId = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientId);
        final EditText clientWallet = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientWallet);
        final EditText clientBalance = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.newClientBalance);

        builder.setPositiveButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String nameValue = clientName.getText().toString().trim();
                        int idValue = Integer.valueOf(clientId.getText().toString().trim());
                        String walletValue = clientWallet.getText().toString().trim();
                        double balanceValue = Double.valueOf(clientBalance.getText().toString().trim());
                        clientListItems.add(new Client(nameValue, idValue, new Wallet(walletValue, balanceValue), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();

    }
}
```

You need to add layout content first then initialize the edittexts.

Comment: Thanks, but it not help.Previous error in previous place.